# How do I change Serde's default implementation to return an empty object instead of null?

Tags: rust, serde, serde-json

I'm developing an API wrapper and I'm having some troubles with the deserialization of an empty JSON object.

The API returns this JSON object. Mind the empty object at `entities`:

```
{
  "object": "page",
  "entry": [
    {
      "id": "1158266974317788",
      "messaging": [
        {
          "sender": {
            "id": "some_id"
          },
          "recipient": {
            "id": "some_id"
          },
          "message": {
            "mid": "mid.$cAARHhbMo8SBllWARvlfZBrJc3wnP",
            "seq": 5728,
            "text": "test",
            "nlp": {
              "entities": {} // <-- here
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my equivalent struct of the `message` property (**edited**):

```
 #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct TextMessage {
    pub mid: String,
    pub seq: u64,
    pub text: String,
    pub nlp: NLP,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct NLP {
    pub entities: Intents,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Intents {
    intent: Option<Vec<Intent>>,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Intent {
    confidence: f64,
    value: String,
}
```

Serde's default is to deserialize `Option`s, which are `None`, with `::serde_json::Value::Null`.

Comment: Why have you chosen a `Vec` to represent a JSON object? How do you expect those values to transfer? In fact, if the API **always** returns an object (or array, whatever), why do you even have an `Option` in your struct?

Comment: Yeah you are right the structure of the structs was wrong. I edited the code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved this problem differently with no need to change the default implementation. I used serde's [field attributes](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html) to skip the `intent` property when the Option is `None`. Because there is only one property in the struct `Intents`, this will create an empty object.

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct TextMessage {
    pub mid: String,
    pub seq: u64,
    pub text: String,
    pub nlp: NLP,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct NLP {
    pub entities: Intents,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Intents {
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if="Option::is_none")]
    intent: Option<Vec<Intent>>,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Intent {
    confidence: f64,
    value: String,
}
```