# How do I avoid generating JSON when serializing a value that is null or a default value?

Tags: rust, serde-json

The `serde_json::to_string()` function will generate a string which may include `null` for an `Option<T>`, or `0` for a `u32`. This makes the output larger, so I want to ignore these sorts of values.

I want to simplify the JSON string output of the following structure:

```
use serde_derive::Serialize; // 1.0.82

#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct WeightWithOptionGroup {
    pub group: Option<String>,
    pub proportion: u32,
}
```

When `group` is `None` and `proportion` is 0, the JSON string should be `"{}"`

Thanks for the answer[How do I change Serde's default implementation to return an empty object instead of null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46993079/how-do-i-change-serdes-default-implementation-to-return-an-empty-object-instead), it can resolve `Option`problem, but for `0` there is none solution.

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I change Serde's default implementation to return an empty object instead of null?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46993079/155423)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change Serde's default implementation to return an empty object instead of null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46993079/how-do-i-change-serdes-default-implementation-to-return-an-empty-object-instead)

Comment: it can resolve `Option` problem, but for 0 there is none solution.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The link [Skip serializing field](https://serde.rs/attr-skip-serializing.html) give me the answer.

And the fixed code:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize, Default, PartialEq, Ord, PartialOrd, Eq)]
pub struct WeightWithOptionGroup {
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    #[serde(default)]
    pub group: Option<String>,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "is_zero")]
    #[serde(default)]
    pub proportion: u32,
}

/// This is only used for serialize
#[allow(clippy::trivially_copy_pass_by_ref)]
fn is_zero(num: &u32) -> bool {
    *num == 0
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of ways you could do this:

- Mark each of the fields with a [`skip_serialising_if`](https://serde.rs/attr-skip-serializing.html) attribute to say when to skip them. This is much easier, but you'll have to remember to do it for every field.
- [Write your own Serde serialiser](https://serde.rs/impl-serializer.html) that does this custom JSON form. This is more work, but shouldn't be too bad, especially given you can still use the stock JSON deserialiser.

Answer (score 2):

For those searching how to skip serialization for some `enum` entries you can do this

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
enum Metadata {
  App,             // want this serialized
  Ebook,           // want this serialized
  Empty            // dont want this serialized
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Request<'a> {
    request_id: &'a str,
    item_type: ItemType,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Metadata::is_empty")]
    metadata: Metadata,
}

impl Metadata {
    fn is_empty(&self) -> bool {
        match self {
            Metadata::Empty => true,
            _ => false,
        }
    }
}
```